# Point Cloud Shrink in size

Tags: python, point-clouds

I have an organized point cloud file of an assembly generated using FreeCAD. I am using open3d python library to visualize this point cloud file. I just wonder whether there's a method to resize (cut down) this point cloud to a smaller size (shrink in size), but keeping this cloud organized in its original shape. That means I want to reduce the spacing between the points so that they become closer and the point cloud compresses while maintaining the shape of the point cloud.

I think this shouldn't be the same as down sampling. What I want to do next is that I want to combine the 2 point clouds together so that the shrinker point cloud object appears to be within the bigger point cloud object

I am working on python using the approach of storing these point clouds in lists etc. and visualizing using open3D python library.

Any advice is welcome, thanks first!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried scaling it?
For example, converting the units from meters to millimeters - multiply/divide each coordinate by the same constant (for example - 1000 for m<->mm conversion).
Then, center each point cloud (subtract the mean from each point) and merge them. You can adjust their centroid and the scaling for better output.